# HP P800 PCI controller disables(!) HP 410i internal controller

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, raid-controller

I have a HP DL360 G6 server with a very strange RAID controller behavior.

I installed a P800 PCI RAID Controller card and all of the sudden I cannot access my hard drives that are connected to the internal P410i controller. To be more precise, the bios automatically disables the P410i interface each and every time I restart.
I already tried updating the BIOS and flashing the P800 to the latest firmware all to no avail I'm afraid. I turned the BIOS upside down looking for something useful but nothing there.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are unable to access the hard drives that are connected internally, do you mean in the BIOS, and you cannot boot from them? 
Do you have many logical drives defined?
Is this legacy BIOS (not EFI)?

If all these questions are yes, then most likely the PCI HBA's OpROM is loading second, and pushing the BBS chain down so that the internal drives are pushed off the bottom. Disabling the OpROM/BIOS on the add-in card is the most straight forward way to deal with this.

Comment: What do you mean "disabling on the add-in card"? Is this something I can access through the bios?

Comment: Normally the BIOS on the RAID card although it can be done through some BIOS for the slot. Check out this page for some tips on changing the order: [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00806102/c00806102.pdf#14)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the P800 to manage the internal disks anyway - you could remove the P410i and reduce overall complexity of the system?

Comment: I didnt have the proper cables for that I'm afraid.